# OpenSSL s_client only returning 2/3 certificates from a chain?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I'm fairly new to OpenSSL, so please bear with me here. I'm attempting to retrieve the root CA certificate from various websites using s_client, but for some reason, it will sometimes not return the final certificate in the chain, which is the one that I need the most.

I'm using the following (on FreeBSD 10.0):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.facebook.com:443
```

To achieve the following output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=CA/L=Menlo Park/O=Facebook, Inc./CN=*.facebook.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=CA/L=Menlo Park/O=Facebook, Inc./CN=*.facebook.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3401 bytes and written 417 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 775663B26F3B0570F8B6BA08243E9079F2A36735BDCB39883D4D6C14A35ADC31
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 096644B949FBA333F6205CD76E4C38519D7413BC2BA20CD307199F40E9B1992EC4A6813B8C28295247C4B2E1B8FDD386
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 172800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 5b d1 e2 4c bd 77 70 f6-0b ac 12 67 27 3f 80 b0   [..L.wp....g'?..
    0010 - e9 1b 02 f7 cc 70 50 10-21 ee 0c a4 37 c2 d9 e1   .....pP.!...7...
    0020 - a9 54 ef 74 c7 12 c9 d5-0f e7 3d e9 59 dc 1d ac   .T.t......=.Y...
    0030 - 8f bb a2 58 ad 92 56 24-dd 29 7b 65 01 53 f3 4d   ...X..V$.){e.S.M
    0040 - cd 05 19 cc dd 00 bc ff-2a bd 16 99 c0 59 2d 7d   ........*....Y-}
    0050 - dd 09 86 02 a1 f2 00 52-2c 84 88 d3 3d 03 93 81   .......R,...=...
    0060 - a3 d2 b3 30 b1 b9 2a e3-fe 45 63 99 e7 3a 24 62   ...0..*..Ec..:$b
    0070 - e4 6a 83 41 45 8c 08 2a-8d fb f1 96 0e c0 3e 26   .j.AE..*......>&
    0080 - cc ad b4 75 3b c3 96 e5-a5 89 c5 3e fa 8d 7c 96   ...u;......>..|.
    0090 - cf 70 b9 99 8a fc 65 5a-9a 34 7d f2 d7 db bb 25   .p....eZ.4}....%
    00a0 - e9 b1 4c b4 3e 1b d6 d5-36 de c0 03 95 e3 93      ..L.>...6......
    00b0 - <SPACES/NULS>

    Start Time: 1468438138
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
closed
```

As you can see, it stops returning certificates after the second one (DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA), and doesn't return the root certificate (DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to force it to return this certificate as well?

And if so, is there a way to force it to return **ONLY** that one, since it's the only one I need?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Root certificates are typically not included in the chain presented during the handshake since it is expected that the client trying to connect to the server already has the root in its trust store.

Comment: Perhpas even [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to learn about PKI and server configurations.

Comment: @jww I suppose I should have mentioned that I'm going to be using this as part of a larger programming project where I'm getting the root certificate from a site and adding it to my machine's /etc/ssl/cacert.pem file, and I couldn't find anything that would help me accomplish what I need to do.

Comment: @jww I'm on Swammy's side here: If I'm writing a program that has to reach out over an SSL connection, and it starts breaking due to cert verification, I need (as a programmer / developer) to be able to debug that. Telling me that it's a system administrator question to fix my SSL connection doesn't help me figure out why my python code is unable to do anything. I get the idea of Web Apps Stack Exchange being a bit better fit, but I don't think it's completely out of the realm of being a legitimate programming / development question. Maybe 20 years ago it would have been.

Answer (score 0):

### Why we're not getting the root certificate

@user2797321's comment makes sense based on my experience trying to chase down a digicert signed certificate:

> Root certificates are typically not included in the chain presented during the handshake since it is expected that the client trying to connect to the server already has the root in its trust store.

[This Security Stack Exchange answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/215987) gives some context from the openssl documentation - with `s_client connect -showcerts` we're only going to see certs that were sent over the wire.

I still need to get that certificate for my own use case, and I'm working on Windows at the moment. So I've populated the Windows instructions, and added a couple of links that seem to get us in the right direction for other OSes - would appreciate anyone who finds this answer on those OSes filling in the details in the corresponding section.

### Export a Root Certificate - Windows

I'm (sadly) working on Windows. I always get weird results when I Google things, and I extrapolate like crazy, so I figured out what to do from [this random confluence page](https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/Exporting+Certificates+from+the+Windows+Certificate+Store#:%7E:text=Certificates%20%3E%20Computer%20account%20%3E%20Next%20%3E,key%22%20then%20%22Next%22.), but to spare you the mental gymnastics, here's a (hopefully) more purpose-built instruction set:

1. Start -> search for "certificate" -> Manage User Certificates (alternatively certmgr seems to work too)
2. Select Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the left; Double Click "Certificates" on the right.
3. Scroll down to the Root cert you want on the right
4. Right Click -> All Tasks -> Export...
5. Follow the prompts, in my case I chose "Base64 encoded X.509 (.CER)" as the export format

### Export a Trusted Root Certificate - Mac OS

[Instructions (untested / require adaptation) for Mac](https://www.leaderssl.com/articles/441-how-to-export-code-signing-certificates-on-mac)

### Export a Trusted Root Certificate - Linux

[Instructions (untested / require adaptation) for Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368123/how-to-extract-the-root-ca-and-subordinate-ca-from-a-certificate-chain-in-linux)